# What exaclty happens when a you call a constructor(new Class),do instance initializer blocks runs first?

Tags: java, oop, object, constructor

Im a complete beginner in the Java especially OOP so please pardon my naivety but recently while going through Head First Java,they said,**A constructor is a code that runs when somebody says *new* on a class type.**
But then i tried this code to see what actually happened but to my surprise the output was totally different.

```
public class Test {
    private int n;
    {System.out.println("Out1 "+n);}
    public Test() {
       n=10;
       System.out.println("Inside Constructor");
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
        Test obj=new Test();
        }
    {System.out.println("Out2 "+n);}
}
```

The Output:
Hello World!
Out1 0
Out2 0
Inside Constructor
My question:WHY?Shouldnt the instance variable get initialized as soon as i call the contructor to initialize the specific instance variable?Isnt that the whole purpose of constructors?to run before making the object!

Comment: Why it wouldnt?I tried it in eclipse!Please justify yourself

Comment: You can't have method invocations directly in the body of a class.

Comment: Hmm point...so i take it Eclipse made a fool of itself?:p

Comment: The program will not compile .

Inside class only you can declare variables & methods but you can't call methods. 

Inside class you have called a methods which is wrong

Comment: Extremely Sorry for the "uncompilable" code.Please re-check!

Comment: Your code is still unappropriate because of the following :- check my answer below!!!

Comment: Has no one heard of initializer blocks???

Comment: @shmosel It's been edited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The constructor executes in the following order:

1. Calls the constructor of the superclass.
2. Runs the [instance initializer blocks](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html) in the order they were defined.
3. Executes the rest of the body of the constructor.

I.e., both of your sysout statements execute just before the assignment `n=10;`. That's how it should be. See [JLS §12.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.5).

Comment: Thanks that clears it!So the jist of the whole thing is that the instance initializer blocks run before any kind of initialization inside constructor?