# Java Class Object Dynamic Memory Allocation

Tags: java, oop, object, constructor

Hey Guys i am new to java programming.I tried to experiment with java classes and what i have done is that i have created an instance variable x and then y which copies that values of x.
Then I define a constructor which takes the value or x as an argument.
Now when i try to print the value of y it gives the value as 0 while or x it gives 5.
Why the problem is happening ?
When we use new keyword and the Constructor then only all the instance fields are created so i feel like after we use

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package test;
/**
 *
 * @author Mridul
 */
public class Test {
int x;
int y=x;
Test(int a)
{
    x=a;

}
void print()
{
    System.out.println(x); 
}
    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test ob=new Test(5);
        ob.print();
        System.out.println(ob.y);


        // TODO code application logic here
    }

}

Output
5
0
```

When we use new keyword and the Constructor then only all the instance fields are created so i feel like after we use

```
Test ob=new Test(5);
```

Then only all the codes in the class(x,y=x) should run and it shouldn't have created the problem.
Please Help

Comment: for `int` `x=a` is a kind of *copy*, any change to `a` is not reflected into `x` after the `=` (and `int x;` is equivalent to `int x = 0`)

Comment: but in output it gives x=5 and y=0

Comment: ... because instance field initialization runs _before_ constructor statements.

Comment: but i am using the constructor and  new keyword .

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24109439/what-exaclty-happens-when-a-you-call-a-constructornew-class-do-instance-initia?rq=1

Comment: What output are you expecting? Do you expect `y` to be `10`?

Comment: i expect y to be 5

Answer (score 0):

When you create a new instance of `Test`, this is happening (in order):

```
int x; // x = 0
int y=x; // y = 0
Test(int a)
{
    x=a; // x = your a value
}
```

=> community wiki, feel free to....

Answer (score 0):

This here:

```
int y=x;
```

happens **once**, **before** your constructor is executed.

Thus the ctor changes the value of x; but y stays at its previous value. (x gets initially the default value of 0; that goes into y; and then the ctor is executed and changes x to the value of a).

And please note: this has nothing to do with "dynamic allocation". `new` causes three things:

- memory is allocated
- fields of the new object are init'ed
- the specified constructor is invoked

(see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4916735/default-constructor-vs-inline-field-initialization) for more details). If you want y to have the same value as x; just do

public class Test
    final int x, y;

```
Test(int incoming) {
  x = incoming;
  y = incoming;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you call a constructor using `new`, then Java begins to construct the newly allocated object. The values of the instance fields (in your case of field `x` and field `y`) are determined by a set of rules.

- First, the instance fields are initialized. `x` has the default value (`0`); `y` gets the value of `x`, which is `0`.
- Then, in the constructor, `x` is set to the value of `a`.

`y` is still `0`, because it gets its value *before* `x` is set to the value of `a`.

Answer (score 0):

`new operator` is for automatic memory allocation, to allocate the needed memory for an object, you must use the `new operator`.